# How to remove the chapter number from section number?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, numbering

I use Roman for Chapter numbers, and I don't want sections to be numbered as VIII.2 (while I still want sections to be numbered within chapters). How do I do that?

i.e. instead of `VIII.2` sections should be numbered as `2`.

EDIT: I saw the other question that people mark this one as a duplicate to. I tried `\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}` and `\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}`, but none of them worked. That's why I asked this question.

2nd Edit: Sorry, now it is solved. I had `\numberwithin{section}{chapter}` after that. After removing it everything is fine.

Answer (score 6):

Try something like `\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}` somewhere before `\begin{document}`. This should work, if not please provide an example of your code, so we can try it.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Heading}

\section{Something else}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the code above]

Answer (score 2):

You may try

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```